# use fit for sklearn gridsearchcv

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm new to Sklearn and python ; I have this code snippet for a project that I'm trying to decipher. I hope you guys can help me with it.

```
from repository import Repository
from configuration import config
repository = Repository(config)
dataset, labels = repository.get_dataset_and_labels()
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.cross_validation import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV  
# Ensure that there are no NaNs
dataset = dataset.fillna(-85)
# Split the dataset into training (90 \%) and testing (10 \%)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset, labels,      test_size = 0.1 )
cv = ShuffleSplit(X_train.shape[0], n_iter=10, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
# Define the classifier to use
estimator = SVC(kernel='linear')
# Define parameter space
gammas = np.logspace(-6, -1, 10)
# Use Test dataset and use cross validation to find bet hyper-p  rameters.
classifier = GridSearchCV(estimator=estimator, cv=cv, param_grid=dict(gamma=gammas))
classifier.fit(X_train, [repository.locations.keys().index(tuple(l))  for l in y_train])
```

what I can't wrap my head around is the use of the fit method of the classifier. In all the examples I found online, 'fit' receives the training data and the corresponding labels. In the example above, 'fit' receives the training data and the indexes of the labels (not the labels). 
How is it that the classifier takes the indexes not the labels and still works

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, where did you get this from? Only reason I'm asking is because you said it works. I don't have `repository` so I can't test it by seeing what `dataset` it's referring to

Comment: @Leb It's a code snippet from an academic project I was assigned to. the dataset is composed of wifi fingerprints (mac address, level of the signal), labels contain the coordinates of that fingerprint in a building.

Comment: Ok, *my guess* is: `from sklearn.cross_validation import ShuffleSplit` returns [indices](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.ShuffleSplit.html). So from the looks of it they did that first and used that in the `GridSearchCV`. That's why the index is being used for `y_train` which I'm assuming it has a shape of (y,) (i.e. columns only)

Comment: @Leb So `classifier.fit` is actually receiving an index list, not the locations saved in `y_train` ?

Comment: It is receiving an index list which is a representation of the location of `y_train`. That is being cross validated using the `ShuffleSplit` that's why you see `cv=cv` for `GridSearchCV`. In other words, `ShuffleSplit` returns indices and in order for those to relate to `y_train` location, a `list` must be passed which is `repository.locations.keys().index(tuple(l))`

Comment: @Leb ok thanks that was really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label is just an abstract term. It can be anything, word, number, index, anything. In your case (whatever is `repository.locations.keys().index(...)`, let us just assume that it is a **deterministic** function, for simplicity lets call it `f`), you create a list

```
 [f(tuple(l)) for l in y_train]
```

`y_train` itself is a list (or more general - iterable). So the above is also a list of labels, simply transformed through `f`, for some other reason (maybe in this particular case user needs simply different set of labels than in the original dataset?). Either way, you still pass **labels** to your `fit` method, they are simply transformed.

Consider for example set of labels `['cat', 'dog']`, it does not really matter whether I train a model on `[x1, x2, x3]`, `['cat', 'cat', 'dog']` or on `[x2,x3,x3]`, `[0, 0, 1]` (indices of labels).

Answer (score -1):

Obviously your labels are encoded here:

```
[repository.locations.keys().index(tuple(l))  for l in y_train]
```

Apart of this, I think it is worth to look at the [SearchGridCV documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html).